# TYPO3: Parse current url into variable

Tags: typo3, typoscript

i know how i get the current URL with typoscript, but i dont know how i can parse this url into a variable so i can use and work with it.

```
temp.getUrl = TEXT
temp.getUrl.typolink {
  parameter.data=TSFE:id
  returnLast=url
}
```

This example returns me an url segment like 'This/is/just/a/test.html', so long – perfect!

Now i try to save this url into an Variable  like

```
temp.getUrl = TEXT
temp.getUrl.typolink {
  parameter.data=TSFE:id
  returnLast=url
}
wiredMindsCompleteUrl < temp.getUrl
```

This results everytime just with 'TEXT' :( i kinda depressed.

Please help :)

Comment: There are no variables in TypoScript. You treat it as a programming language which it's not. `<` operator doesn't copy the output of `temp.getUrl` but simply copies the whole configuration into `wiredMindsCompleteUrl`. You should better specify what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Also, your are not **getting** the current URL. You are **creating** the link for the current page. There's quite a difference in that.

Comment: Of course you can specify variables in TS using the constants.

Comment: Those are not variables as in programming languages and you cannot work with them the way you are attempting.

Answer (score 0):

The question is, where do you want to use it.

If you want to use it in different places in TypoScript you can f.e. render it into stdWrap.append / stdWrap.prepend of your links.

```
 myMenu = HMENU
 myMenu ...
 myMenu.stdWrap.append < temp.getUrl
```

You could just put it into an Register:

```
  page.1.LOAD_REGISTER
  page.1.getUrl < temp.getUrl
```

and f.e. use your register in the tilte-Tag of an image:

```
  lib.MyImage = IMAGE
  lib.MyImage.file = ...
  lib.MyImage.titleText.data = REGISTER:getUrl
  lib.MyImage.tilteText.noTrimWrap = | makes no sense (IMHO:) ||
```

If you need it in your extension, just use it with cObjGetSingle.

```
 plugin.tx_yourextension_pi1.getUrl < temp.getUrl
```

Inside your extension use it via

```
  function main($content, $conf) {
     $this->conf = $conf;
     return $this->cObj->cObjGetSingle($this->conf['getUrl'], $this->conf['getUrl.'], 'getUrl');
  }
```

Side note: use lib.getUrl instead of temp.getUrl, otherwise you can get in trouble with non-cached TypoScript parts.